# Advanced Custom Field Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Объясните мне пожалуйста как создать поле в advanced custom field чтобы отобразился как поля для поиска?

Вот этот код отображает содержимое поля "search_short_kod"

[image: Вот этот код берет содержимое поля "search_short_kod"]

Comment: А зачем ACF для поля поиска? Чем родной поиск не угодил?

Comment: этот код не я написал. Дали чтобы я востановил доступ к сайту

Comment: Ещё лучше... Причем тут доступ к сайт к тому, что ты написал?  Почему дали тебе, а не тому кто хоть самую малость понимает в  ВП. Скажи пусть работают со специалистом пока ты не поломал им сайт.